# Meaning of Sentence Using Is/Are or Exist?

Tags: existentials

What is the exact meaning of sentences with and without *is* and *are*?
Please explain the example below.

> a) At least we will come to know how many trees "are" exist in
>   the town.
>
> b) At least we will come to know how many trees exist in the
>   town.

Please, help me to understand the verb *exist* with the examples:

Is the structure of the sentence "We are exist and others are living" correct?

Comment: Neither sentence is even approximately grammatical. *SUBJ will come to know how many trees exist in the town* is probably what you want.

Comment: Yes StoneyB you are correct. I have missed Subject in question. I have updated question now. Please answer

Comment: Still not corrected correctly! *a* is incorrect grammatically

Comment: Suhail plz correct me

Comment: A combination of two verb forms such as "are+exist" is not possible in English.

Comment: "We are Exist and others are living" is this sentence formation is corret?

Comment: I think still those above sentences are not grammatical, and it's not only because of **are exist**, but because of the inclusion of **that**. Am I right, @StoneyB?

Comment: @Man_From_India It's really the collocation of *that* with a question, *How ...*. OP might mean "... come to know that many trees exist ...".

Comment: @StoneyB Is it common? :-O Or is it just because of **know**?

Comment: @Man_From_India Many verbs take both *wh-* complements and *that* complements, but in presentday English two complementizers on one clause is one complementizer too many. (EModE still tolerated a *wh-* word followed by *that*, but that was 300+ years ago.)

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks :-) so it's also archaic? I mean our sentence? Yes OED lists some examples of *wh-word* + *that* pattern.

Comment: @Man_From_India Not exactly. In the old construction the *that* has to follow the *wh-* term.

Comment: @StoneyB But then *"but in presentday English two complementizers on one clause is one complementizer too many"* is confusing :O

Comment: By the way what is **EModE**?

Comment: @Man_From_India *Wh-* interrogatives and *that* both act as complementizers. EModE is Early Modern English.

Comment: I think this question should be closed.  It's not intelligible in the current state, and if the OP isn't going to come back and rectify it, it will stand as a poor question/answer pair that helps no one.

Answer (score 3):

The verb "to be" and its various forms (am, is, are) can be used, broadly speaking, in two ways:

- As a primary verb:

  - Today **is** a beautiful day.
  - My parents **are** from Germany.
  - Sometimes, I **am** unhappy.
- As an auxiliary verb, i.e. a verb that helps other verbs create new meanings:

  - I **am watching** a movie. ('to be' + 'watch' creates the present continuous tense)
  - The boys **are playing** outside in the sun. (again, 'to be' + 'play' + '-ing' = present continuous)

Finally, we have the expression "there is" or "there are", as in the following examples:

- **There are** three chairs in the living room. (= The living room **has** three chairs)
- **There is** a good reason for everything (= Everything **has** a good reason)
- In the past, **there were** many diseases that we don't have today. (= In the past, many diseases **existed** that we don't have today).

The last example is related to yours, because we can use "there is", "there are", etc to talk about the existence of something. That gives us two correct ways to express your example sentence:

> At least we will come to know how many trees **there are** in town.

or

> At least we will come to know how many trees **exist** in town.

Your first example sentence with 'are exist' is incorrect, because it tries to use both of the above ways at the same time. Pick just one, and you have a correct version.

Comment: Well now that you know that you can use "there is" and its other forms to talk about existence, you can translate it into other verbs based on context. It's important to remember that the context drives which synonyms for "exist" make sense. For example: "**there is** no solution to this math problem" - you can say "no solution **exists** for this math problem", or "no solution **has been found** for this math problem", etc. Use your context creatively ;)

Comment: RuslanD. "People are gathered in hall" is correct or not? also what would be past tense for my earliar example. i.e. Tree example.

Comment: The formula is "there" + "to be" in the right tense and number. So in the past it becomes "at least we came to know how many trees **there were** in town". Your question about the people in the hall seems different from this topic.

Comment: RuslanD Please give me some more Verb example as "Exist"

Comment: RuslanD. "We are Exist and others are living" is this sentence formation is corret?

Comment: "we are exist" is incorrect, because "are exist" is not a valid verb form. You need to use the present simple tense - "we exist". The verb "exist", together with other verbs like "believe", isn't used in the present continuous tense (e.g. "we are existing"), because continuous tenses are all about what's happening right now. However, something either exists or it doesn't; and you either believe something or you don't - the "right now" makes no difference. So you would say "we exist and others are living", although that's a strange-sounding sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I assume OP's initial *At least we will come to* isn't at issue here, so let's reduce #1 to...

> 1: **✳** *We know <strike>that</strike> how many trees are exist in the town.*

Where **✳** denotes "unacceptable to native speakers". (I've also removed the syntactically invalid ***that***, capital ***Trees***, and quotes around *"**are**"*).

The reason #1 is an invalid construction is because ***are*** and ***exist*** are both finite verb forms performing the same syntactic function (approximately, that of a [copula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28linguistics%29) linking ***trees*** to ***in the town***). We can make it grammatical by removing *either* word,...

> 1a: *We know how many trees **are** in the town.*
>    1b: *We know how many trees **exist** in the town.*

...or by replacing ***exist*** with an *adjectival* form, giving the starchy/formal, but perfectly valid...

> 1c: *We know how many trees **are extant** in the town.*

Note that *in principle* we could replace ***exist*** with a [continuous participle](http://englishwithlucy.com/vtcontinuous2.htm), but idiomatically we wouldn't normally use ***are existing*** (probably because of the semantic overlap between ***to be*** and ***to exist***). Though there's nothing unusual about, say,...

> 1d: *We know how many foreigners **are living** in the town.*

---

I'd guess ***to be*** is the most common verb in English (because of its use as an [auxiliary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be)), but we don't actually use it very often as a "true" verb in the sense of ***to exist***. It's just that some examples ([*"To **be** or not to **be**"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_be,_or_not_to_be) and [*"I think therefore I **am**"* come to mind](http://quotes.yourdictionary.com/articles/who-said-i-think-therefore-i-am.html)) are particularly well-known.

---

TL;DR: If the intended meaning is ***to exist***, use that verb. You won't go far wrong if you only ever use ***to be*** as an auxiliary verb,

Answer (score 0):

> We exist, and others are living.

The sentence means that you are not living, you just exist. Basically, it has the meaning that you live worse than others.

*exist* has the meanings:

> 1. have objective reality or being (Oxford Dictionaries Online)
> 2. occur or be found, especially in a particular place or situation (Oxford Dictionaries Online)

The verb *be/is/are* has more grammatical functions (see the question: [What is meant by the verb "to be"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52634/what-is-meant-by-the-verb-to-be)) than *exist*, but it can be the synonyms of *exist* in a particular context. *exist* has more narrow meaning than the verb *be/is/am*. As the definitions given above say: *exist* is about the existence/being in the objective reality, you can use *be/is/are* instead to *exist* but you cannot always use *exist* instead of *be/is/are*.

***are/is* cannot be used with *exist* because it would be two words with similar meaning and grammatical function (they are verbs) at the same place.** You cannot just say: *I say say...*

Of course, in the spoken language, if the person says two words at the same moment it just the situation of the speaking act when we can use stylistically many words.

More examples from the BNC:

> The opportunity exists today.
>
> The file does not exist.
>
> He exists but it is not true.

Answer (score -1):

English is brief.

At least we'll know how many trees **existing** in the town.

At least we'll know how many trees **staying** in the town.

At least we'll know how many tress **remaing** in the town.

We must learn a lot vocabulary.

Comment: I think those sentences are not at all correct in written English at least due to the want of an auxiliary verb, here **are** that is. But I feel the infinitive form of those verbs that are marked in bold is better. And **stay** is very less likely in here, though it might be a good choice in some other context. I'm not very sure about that.